# Negative form of a secondary verb

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

What should be done with the secondary verb of a sentence? 
Example:

> 1. *The internet is making people **don't** read* or
> 2. *The internet is making people **not** read*

As far as I know, we don't conjugate a secondary verb, therefore the second sentence would be right. But it sounds very strange to me.

Comment: It sounds strange because it's not a particularly well-worded question. It's "correct" but could use rephrasing... "Due to internet usage, people aren't reading any more."

Comment: #2 is the grammatical version.   *The heat is making me **not want** to work in the garden.*   The secondary complement of "making" is a clause headed by the bare infinitive (... making me **want** to work) and the negated form is (... making me not want...).   *The intense heat is making me **not enjoy** the picnic.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#2 is the grammatical version.

The heat is making me not want to work in the garden. The secondary complement of "making" is a clause headed by the bare infinitive (... making me want to work) and the negated form is (... making me not want...). The intense heat is making me not enjoy the picnic. – Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment moved to answer under cc licence

You can, in many cases rephrase to avoid the negative:

> The internet is reducing reading.
>
> The internet has caused fewer people to read books regularly.
>
> The recent reduction in reading is due to the growth of internet use.